# start a new shell inside .*sh file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipenv

I do not know Linux very well and I am sure something like this was asked before in some form, but apparently I am not googling it right.

I have a shell script **script.sh**, which activates another shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

pipenv shell
cat main.py
```

I want `cat main.py` command to run inside `pipenv shell`.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know pipenv, but how about `pipenv run cat main.py`? see documentation here:
https://github.com/pypa/pipenv#-usage